# How to reach the end of a chain of cells

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I have a file with two sheets:

sheet_A

```
  A        B
1 Mr. Joe  USD
```

sheet_B

```
A              B
1 =sheet_A.A1 ???
```

`sheet_B.B1` shall show the value `USD`. I know i could get it easily with `=sheet_A.B1` but I do not want that.

If I enter into `sheet_B.B1` `=ADDRESS(ROW();COLUMN()-1)` I get the output $C$1 and with `=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW();COLUMN()-1))` `Mr. Joe`.

How can I "navigate" through a chain `sheet_B.B1 - sheet_B.A1 - sheet_A.A1 - sheet_A.B1`?

**Edit 1**

Maybe I need something like this

`=OFFSET(FORMULA(ADDRESS(ROW();COLUMN()-1);0;1)`#

sheet_B.B2 shall show the content of sheet_A.B2 in relation of the value in sheet_B.A1

Comment: I'm not sure what is meant by "navigate," nor what the chain of references indicates, but my answer offers two approaches that may meet your needs.  Also, perhaps your problem could be solved by a better understanding of relative references (they automatically adjust when filling or moving), although it's hard to be sure without some explanation of what you're trying to accomplish.  Note: `=ADDRESS(ROW();COLUMN()-1)` produces `$A$1`, not `$C$1`.

Comment: OK, I understand the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two possibilities.  Either formula produces `USD` in `sheet_B.B1`.

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW();COLUMN();;;"sheet_A"))
=VLOOKUP(A1;$sheet_A.A1:B1;2)
```

Documentation: [ADDRESS](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Spreadsheet_Functions#ADDRESS), [VLOOKUP](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Spreadsheet_Functions#VLOOKUP).

**EDIT**:

One more idea:  The following produces the string "=sheet_A.A1", which could be parsed for the sheet name and cell address.  Perhaps you would like to use it to refer to sheet_A.B1.

```
=FORMULA(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW();COLUMN()-1)))
```

However, as I commented, there is probably an easier way for what you are trying to accomplish.

Documentation: [FORMULA](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Information_Functions#FORMULA).

**EDIT 2**:

Here is the formula you requested.  It uses [REPLACE](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Text_Functions#REPLACE) to remove `=` at the beginning of the string.

```
=OFFSET(INDIRECT(REPLACE(FORMULA(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW();COLUMN()-1)));1;1;""));0;1)
```

Comment: I would need something like this
`=OFFSET(FORMULA(ADDRESS(ROW();COLUMN()-1);0;1)`
in sheet_B.B2 to show the content of sheet_A.B2

Comment: @user1587451: Edit 2 gives the answer you are asking for, although I cannot imagine a spreadsheet that would benefit from such trickery.  Let me recommend once again to take a step back and consider what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: That is quite a long formula. But it is working as expected. I am using it for a small project balance sheet with accounts with identical name but different currencies. Thanks